# changing the sidebarPanel with navbarPage in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I'm working with the sidebarPanel, using navbarPage.

I would like to "declare" only one widget (radioButtons in this example), then link each tab to the "main" sidebarPanel. As you can see, tab2 is not reactive to the relative radioButtons.
The structure of my project is more complex, having the necessity to have the same sidebarPanel for some tabs and a specific sidebarPanel for some other tabs.
This is the code I'm using:

```
library(shiny)

server=function(input, output) {  
  output$plot1 = renderPlot({plot(runif(input$rb))})
  output$plot2 = renderPlot({plot(runif(input$rb))})
}



ui = shinyUI(navbarPage("Test multi page",                        
  tabPanel("tab1",                      
          sidebarLayout(
            sidebarPanel(
              radioButtons("rb","Nr of obs:",choices = c("50 obs"=50,"300 obs"=300))
            ),
            mainPanel(plotOutput("plot1"))
          )
          ),

  tabPanel("tab2",                      
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        radioButtons("rb","Nr of obs:",choices = c("50 obs"=50,"300 obs"=300))
       ),
      mainPanel(plotOutput("plot2"))
    )
  )

))

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

runApp("app")
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot re-use ui-elements in the way you want. The closest you can get would be to use conditionalPanel. In the example below `fixed` would be the input you want to have on multiple pages. Conditional panel will let you add ui components based on the active tab where `tabid` is the id-label for your tabsetPanel. You don't have to use renderUI and uiOutput here but it will probably make things easier for you if you have a lot of tabs and ui-elements. To see an example take a look at [this app](http://vnijs.rady.ucsd.edu:3838/quant/) and click through the tabs for the Data menu.

```
sidebarPanel(
  uiOutput("fixed"),
  conditionalPanel("input.tabid == 'tab1'", uiOutput("ui_tab1")),
  ....
)
mainPanel(
  tabsetPanel(id = "tabid",
  ...
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you have two input widgets with the `inputId` set to `rb`. If you change the code in `tab2` to:

```
radioButtons("rb2","Nr of obs:",choices = c("50 obs"=50,"300 obs"=300))
```

and then connect this to `output$plot2` in the `server`:

```
output$plot2 = renderPlot({plot(runif(input$rb2))})
```

the app will work.

I assume the reason that this is happening is because shiny will remember the values of the widgets even when they are not visible. So you could easily end up with one value of `rb` in `tab1` and a different value of `rb` in `tab2`. In that case it would not be clear what should be plotted, so the second `rb` is being ignored.

Comment: Hi, it seems my example was not very clear, sorry for this. My project is very "complex", that is with a big number of tabs. I would like to declare the widget only once, then link it to my tabs (without repeating the radioButtons command in each tab).